# Template handler methods

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I want to have different handlers for different kind of messages, each message is identified by an `int`. I want to define each handler as an instantiation of a template method.

The idea is something like this:

handlers.h

```
enum Handler {
    MESSAGE1,
    MESSAGE2
};

template<MESSAGE1>
void handle() {
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    handle<Handler::MESSAGE>();
}
```

Of course this code does not compile because `MESSAGE1` is not a type.
So, how could I create a different type for each message ? Also, I'd like to maintain the use of these types as meaningful as possible (hence the use of enums).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want what's called *non-type template parameters* with *template specialization*:

```
template<Handlers H> void handle();  // default

template<> void handle<MESSAGE1>() {
    // ...
}

template<> void handle<MESSAGE2>() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::integral_constant` (or write your own empty type wrapper to do the same thing) to wrap your enums into types:

```
template <Handler H>
using handle_t = std::integral_constant<Handler, H>;
```

And then overload on different types:

```
void handle(handle_t<MESSAGE1> ) { ... }
void handle(handle_t<MESSAGE2> ) { ... }
```

which you can call via:

```
handle(handle_t<MESSAGE1>{} );
```